# Limit logging to only one jar log4j

Tags: java, log4j

I have a project which is in turn used by several other projects. I want `log4j` to log only my logs to a file that I have specified in the properties file. Other project use their own logging mechanisms and I have no control over them. My log4j files should not affect other project's logging. How should i configure my log4j property file?

So far what I'm doing is setting `log4j.rootLogger = ERROR` and for my module `log4j.logger.com.xyz.myproject = INFO, FILE`. Will this work without affecting other project's loggers? Or possibly limit logging to only my jar?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the package structure of the other projects. Supposing that

- loggers from other projects are created by `Logger.getLogger(ClassA.class)` AND
- some of them rely on root logger configuration (have no specific `log4j.category.loggerName` settings AND
- these projects contain subpackages of the package used by your project (i.e. your project's package is `com.abc.def` and other projects have packages deeper in the hierarchy `com.abc.def.ghi` THEN

changing `com.abc.def` logging level would affect other projects - they'll start logging on the level defined by `com.abc.def`.

Verify that it's not the case and you should be safe.

Comment: Just confirming, all three conditions need to be satisfied right?

Comment: @VarunAchar Yes, exactly like "ANDs" suggest :) I perceive the case I described as the most likely to exist, but surely one could devise uncommon logging schemes that would come in conflict with your approach.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose your jar is entirely contained in your own package (ex com.foo.mypackage). In this case, is just enough to add to your log4j configuration something like:

```
# Print only messages of priority WARN or above in the package com.foo
log4j.category.com.foo=WARN
# Print only messages of priority DEBUG or above in the package com.foo.mypackage
log4j.category.com.foo.mypackage=DEBUG
```

Regards,

M.